# What is best way to manage a Druid cluster?

Tags: druid

Is there any tool/application available to manage a [Druid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druid_(open-source_data_store)) cluster like YARN.

Any suggestion for how to manage a Druid cluster? YARN is not available for Druid?

[Imply](https://imply.io/) seems not to manage like YARN cluster management.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you call management of the cluster. But with HDP distribution, we use Ambari to manage Druid cluster. By managing I mean start/stop nodes, manage configs and related rolling updates.

[Here is a 30 min video](https://youtu.be/pvtdvoZ83uk) about how to use HDP to run Druid.